# What is the script of Glossy BSDF roughness value?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, shader-nodes

This is the script I am working on

```
BsdfGlossy_node = material_gold.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfGlossy')
        BsdfGlossy_node.location = (0,-100)
        BsdfGlossy_node.outputs[0].default_value = (0.144, 1, 0.8, 1)
        BsdfGlossy_node.select = False
        BsdfGlossy_node.hide = True
```

I want to know the roughness value script

[image]

Also, how can I script the colour of this node? I tried `BsdfGlossy_node.outputs[0].default_value`
but it has an error
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BsdfGlossy_node.inputs['Roughness'].default_value`

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Also works with `BsdfGlossy_node.inputs[1].default_value` which is locale-independant

Comment: Does it really use the locale? Using the index [can break](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/implement-new-node-parameters-without-breaking-existing-scripts/15433) if new sockets are added.

Comment: Switching the Language in _Preferences > Interface_ does not change the names of sockets in Python for me.